# Why is thread priority not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable 
{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Exiting1");
    }



public static void main(String[] args)
 {

System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());   

Thread1 i=new Thread1();
Thread t=new Thread(i);
t.setPriority(8);
System.out.println(t.getPriority());
t.start();

System.out.println("Exiting");
    }
}
```

Here I have a doubt that I have set the priority of my thread higher then main() thread then why is the sopln() in main() is executing first. My thread should execute first so it should execute run() method's sopln() first then main() method's sopln.

Comment: `sopln()` ?  What `sopln()` ?  (Hint: this is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @MikeNakis sopln -> System.out.println

Comment: And hint: you want us to spend our time to help you, so it would be appropriate to properly format / indent all of your source code input; instead of dropping such a mess here. And beyond that: try using your favorite search engine the next time. This is really something that comes up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

See [Oracle docs : Background Information: Java Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/thread-priorities.html#javabackground)

> A JVM is free to implement priorities in any way it chooses, **including ignoring the value**.

My emphasis.

Although this doc is specifically about the Solaris implementation it should apply to all JVMs.

Comment: Although a duplicate question, a nice concise precise answer.

Comment: but if A JVM is free to implement priorities in any way it chooses, including ignoring the value. then what is the use of thread priority?

Comment: @Ankit It is an archaic feature of Java. If you need to ensure some form of ordering for multiple threads then there are many other techniques. If they need to exchange information then a `BlockingQueue` is useful. If all you want is a lock-step moment then try `CountDownLatch`.